# Rails 5 migrations using UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to mix the new table migration syntax for UUID with the old auto incrementing id?

I'm using the postgres extension for uuid and the 5.2 syntax `id: :uuid`

```
enable_extension "uuid-ossp" # enables UUID extension for postgresql
```

As an example, for one table can I would like to use uuids:

```
...
create_table :answers, id: :uuid do
...
```

And on another table I'd UUIDs aren't needed so I'd like to use auto incrementing integer ids:

```
...
create_table :questions do
...
```

As this is a limitation imposed by rails, my expected behavior would be the ability to override UUID via an explicit call in the migration to declare the table id as integer. Something along the lines of:

```
...
create_table :answers, id: :integer do
...
```

It seems to be all or nothing to me, unless I'm not finding something in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I had enabled this feature of Rails

https://www.mccartie.com/tech/2015/10/20/default-uuid's-in-rails.html

And it was forcing all my primary_keys to uuid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uuid only for new tables. And the old table will keep the same increment.
To use UUID as primary key you can check on this tutorial:
https://uysim.com/use-uuid-as-primary-key-in-ruby-on-rails/